# Safe hidden text in HTML?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, html, spam-prevention

I need to have some hidden text in HTML to parse as text when i read an actual HTML file
I used to include my text in hidden div using style but i knew that may record us as spammers in SEO

```
.hideme {
position : absolute;
left : -1000px;
}
```

Can i have this content as commented text in the HTML ?

will that be safe as i know that SEO crawlers ignores the comments in HTML

```
<!-- my hidden text -->
```

Please advice

Answer (score 5):

The search engines only care about hidden text when it is used to manipulate a page's rankings. Typically this is defined as content that is presented to the search engines that is not presented to users. So if you hide text so users can't see it but crawlers can you will find yourself having issues with Google. An example of when hiding text is good is when you use `display:none` to hide dynamic content and then use JavaScript or CSS to display the content when an action is performed (i.e. mouseover, etc).

If you place this extra content within comments as you suggest in your question you will be fine as this content is not available to users and search engines ignore comments.

Comment: So the Google Spider is interpreting jQuery code and understands that hidden texts might become visible if the user hovers over certain areas on the page?

Comment: Possibly. If there bot can't do it a human review will. (Yes, they do human reviews).

Comment: Why they don't regard display:none as hidden text?

Comment: It *is* hidden text. But hidden text *isn't bad* unless it is *used to manipulate a page's rankings*

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid "hide" in naming your CSS class.

But the best way is to avoid hidden text by finding easy and creative ways to add the text to the content of a web-page without seeming like spam.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse html comments so instead use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="my text" name="my_hidden_field/>
```

Comment: i am not parsing text in the code behind i read the file, anyways are you sure that search engines doesn't consider this as a way of spamming ?

Comment: It will be fine. Please read this for how to avoid getting in trouble with google: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769  Also found on that same page is a link to this article which defines exactly what is considered to be hidden text: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66353  Since you're reading the file and not parsing it, then you can include the hidden field using comment tags.

Answer (score 0):

Some  people for SEO doing this :

```
.hideme {       
 width:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-indent:-99999px
}
```

Why you do not use `<meta> tags`  ?

Comment: You should really explain this further as doing what you suggest without making that content visible through some sort of action is black hat SEO and a reason to be banned from the search engines.